# Get indices from np.array under condition from another array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy array (5×5) with distances between points.
The matrix is square and symmetrical.

```py
distances = np.array([
    [0, 3, 2, 1, 4],
    [3, 0, 1, 3, 5],
    [2, 1, 0, 7, 6],
    [1, 3, 7, 0, 9],
    [4, 5, 6, 9, 0],
    ])
```

I also have a `points` list of 5 elements as following:

```py
points = ["A", "D", "A", "D", "F"]
```

so that, for example, the distance between the first `"A"` and the first `"D"` of the points list is `distances[0, 1]`, which is `3`.

Is it possible, using the `np.where()` function to get the indices where the distance is less than `2`, the first point is `"A"` and the second point is `"D"`? That is, to get `[0, 4]` and `[2, 1]`?

If I use `np.where((distances <= 2) & (distances > 0))` I get the indices of the array for all values `<=2`. I want to get the indices for those values `<= 2`, where the first point is `"A"` and the second point is `"D"`.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your expected output?

Comment: I think the output in your example should be `[0, 3]` and `[2, 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
In [152]: import numpy as np

In [153]: points = np.array(['A', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'F'], dtype='str')

In [154]: distances = np.array(
     ...:     [[0, 3, 2, 1, 4],
     ...:      [3, 0, 1, 3, 5],
     ...:      [2, 1, 0, 7, 6],
     ...:      [1, 3, 7, 0, 9],
     ...:      [4, 5, 6, 9, 0]])

In [155]: first = 'A'

In [156]: second = 'D'

In [157]: threshold = 2

In [158]: rows = np.flatnonzero(points == first)

In [159]: cols = np.flatnonzero(points == second)

In [160]: ixgrid = np.ix_(rows, cols)

In [161]: idx1, idx2 = np.where(distances[ixgrid] <= threshold)

In [162]: np.stack([rows[idx1], cols[idx2]]).T
Out[162]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```